# "unexpected reloc type 0xe7" when porting c++ shared library to python

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a C++ library and I want to port it to Python.

I'm not sure I know how C++ library works, my program is linked with `link_dir/mylib.so` but actually it needs the library files in some other directory in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when loading. So I need to `set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, otherwise it can not load the correct library.

I wrote some code to wrap the library and wanted to port it to Python via boost.python by making another shared library.

When I use the library in a C++ program, it works fine. When I try to import it in Python, it gives this error
`ImportError: /usr/local/lib/mylib.so: unexpected reloc type 0xe7`, what does it mean?

I've tried making it load same library files it was linked to and importing it in Python, then the error was gone, but clearly that's not the correct library.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is like

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)
link_directories(link_dir)

# packages need by boost python
find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories (${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS python)
include_directories (${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# when importing this pylib in python it gives the error
add_library(pylib SHARED pylib.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(pylib boost_python ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} mylib.so)

# using the shared lib in c++ works fine
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main pylib)
```

Please help.

**Update**
I don't know what I was doing but I tried loading the C++ library directly and got the following.

```
# this gives the same error message
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("load_dir/mylib.so")

# this is fine
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("link_dir/mylib.so")
```

Could it be the problem of `load_dir/mylib.so`? But it works well in other c++ programs for a long time.

Comment: Can you checksum the files in `load_dir/mylib.so` and `link_dir/mylib.so` - e.g. using `md5sum`to verify that they're the same files - I have a suspicion that one of them is a libtool script and that's where the error is coming from; otherwise it's complaining about a reloc for a PARISC architecture, which is pretty unlikely.

Comment: @Petesh thank u, they are not the same files, indeed if I use `load_dir/mylib.so` for linking, it will give me the error like `can not find reference to some_function`. I don't know what is a libtool script though, how would you suggest I fix that?